# Batch file doesn't run correctly within Windows 10

Tags: batch-file

I have a merge.bat file which includes the following line:

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> mergedfile.txt
```

This code line works perfectly if I enter it directly into a cmd window.

All the txt files are located in the same folder as this merge.bat file.

However, when I try to run it as a batch file under cmd i.e. call merge.bat it shows the following message:

```
f" >> mergedfile.txt was unexpected at this time
```

What I would like to do is setup the merge.bat file to run in the Windows 10 task scheduler at a set time, but I just can't get the .bat file to run correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in a batch file you must replace `%` with `%%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add double % signs in batch file in loops.use the following code:

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> mergedfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. This has resolved it. So simple when you know how!

Comment: @BradS if the answer helped you ,consider accepting it by a voteup.

Comment: You could mention that if the user would have read the help file for the `FOR` command they would have read that on about the 7th line of the help file.

Comment: @Squashman thank-you